# The sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\quad2{x}_{n+1}=1+{y}^{2}_{n}，\quad 2{y}_{n+1}=2{x}_{n}-{x}^2_{n},\quad n\in\mathbb{N};\quad 0\leq {y}_{0}\leq \frac{1}{2}\leq {x}_{0}\leq 2.$

Prove that the sequences $ \begin{Bmatrix}
{x}_{n}\end{Bmatrix},\begin{Bmatrix}
{y}_{n}\end{Bmatrix}
$ converges in $\mathbb{R}.$

Note that:

Of course, there must be more than one way to solve this,but I want to use the Limit superior and limit inferior of the sequences $ \{{x}_{n}\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ to get the conclusion.
Can someone help me to solve this question in my way of thinking?

Comment: Your question has a small problem, namely how do you know the inequality on $x_n$ and $y_n$? You need to prove it don't you? Or do you mean that $0 \le y_0 \le \frac{1}{2} \le x_0$?

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Why can't I register my account ? I click on the "sign up"  botton,but webpage have absolutely no response .who can help me to solve this problem effectively?

Comment: You're already registered, otherwise you wouldn't be able to post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Start with
$0\leq {y}_{0}\leq \frac{1}{2}\leq {x}_{0}\leq 2$
and
${x}_{n+1}=1+{y}^{2}_{n}，2{y}_{n+1}=2{x}_{n}-{x}^2_{n}$.

$2y_{n+1}-1
=2{x}_{n}-{x}^2_{n}-1
=-(x_n-1)^2
$
and
$x_{n+1}-1
=y_n^2
$.

Therefore
$2y_{n+1}-1
=-y_{n-1}^4
$
or
$y_{n+1}
=\dfrac{1-y_{n-1}^4}{2}
$

Note that
$-1 \le 2y_1-1 \le 0$
or
$0 \le y_1 \le \frac12$.

$x_1 = 1+y_0^2$,
so
$1 \le x_1 \le \frac54$
and
$0 \ge 2y_2-1
\ge -\frac1{16}
$
or
$\frac{15}{32}
\le y_2
\le \frac12
$.

If
$f(y) =\dfrac{-y^4+1}{2} $
for $0 \le y \le \frac12$,
$f'(y) = -2y^3$
so
$|f'(y)|
\le \frac14
$.
By the standard fixed-point theorem,
the iteration
$y_{n+1} = f(y_n)$
converges to the the root of
$f(y) = y$
on $[0, \frac12]$,
if the root exists.
Since
$f(0) > 0$
and
$f(\frac12)
< \frac12$,
$f$ does have such a root
so the iteration does converge.

Therefore $y_n$
converges to the
root of
$f(y) = y$
which is in $(0, \frac12)$.
If we call this $L$,
$x_n$ converges to
$1+L^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,  although it is not the way I want it done.